# Java Multiple annotations on methods : Good DataStructure to store

Tags: java, data-structures, object-oriented-analysis

I have classes with many methods, some of which are marked by annotations. Each method can have many annotations like

```
@StepAnnotation(name="Action1" ) 
@SequenceAnnotation(name="transactionA" sequenceID="5")
public void doSomeStuff() {

//Perform some stuffs here, calling API or performing some DB actions

}
```

We have an execution engine which is step based and each step has a corresponding annotated Method or a list of Methods which provides the required inputs for the engine for executing that particular step. Sometimes, instead of a Step, we have a Sequence which basically is a list of steps with an id for complex inputs. The steps will be sorted based on id and executed by that engine.

Using reflections, I build an index of the methods that needs to be invoked for a series of Steps or a particular sequence during the runtime. I scan the classes, get the annotated methods and then build the index and invoke them based on the test inputs.

Currently, I am using a `Map<String , Method>` to store the Steps and `Map<String , List<Method>>` to store the sequence.

I was wondering, if there is any good Data Structure for storing the above mentioned data. What Data Structure would be good for both storing / iterating and retrieving the Steps / Sequences for the same?

Comment: DS for Data Structures. edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

You should create specific beans classes to improve your design.

For example you need some like a *Workflow* class as it is below:

```
class Workflow {
    public String name;
    public List<ActionStep> steps;
    // methods....
}
```

And then an *ActionStep* class like so:

```
class ActionStep {
    public String name;
    public Method method;
    // methods ....
}
```

Of course you should add all the proper methods you need like getter and setter and even constructors in the classes.

So you finish with a collection of *Workflow*s, or you could still have a map if you need an index for a fast access.

The advantage of this data structure is to expose the meaning of each association. 
A *name* and a *Method* are a step of some workflow, and so a *name* and a list of *ActionStep* are a workflow.

Increase of maintainability of the code.

I guess the class's names, but you could use the better name that fit your purpose.